# Campo checkbox / switch en Laravel

Tags: laravel, formularios, bootstrap-switch

Estoy usando una plantilla de Creative Tim para mi primer proyecto de Laravel: Argon Pro 2 para Laravel, no consigo que el formato de campo form-switch funcione cuando utilizo Eloquent para mi Crud. Con HTML funciona perfectamente ¿Alguna idea?

Código HTML (Blade)

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
<input id="repetition" name="repetition" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="CheckRepetition" value="{{ old('repetition') }}">
<label class="form-check-label" for="CheckRepetition">Activa para Repetición</label>
</div>
```

Código Eloquent:

```
<div class="col-3 mb-3">
    {{ Form::label('Tarea Repetitiva Checkbox *') }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('repetition', $task->repetition, ['class' => 'form-switch ' .($errors->has('repetition') ? ' is-invalid' : '')]) }}
    {!! $errors->first('repetition', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
</div>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arreglado, así queda el código:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-2 mb-3">
                {{ Form::label('Tarea Repetitiva') }}
                {{ Form::hidden('repetition', '0') }}
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                {{ Form::checkbox('repetition', '1', $task->repetition, ['class' => 'form-check-input' . ($errors->has('repetition') ? ' is-invalid' : '')]) }}
                </div>
                {!! $errors->first('repetition', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```